# Separating the front end from the backend. Spring-boot and Angular2

Tags: angularjs, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out how to separate the frontend from the backend. Example----

---

`DemoProject`------

---

```
  -----------`backend` (module)
      -------`frontend` (module)
```

`src`

---

pom.xml

Frontend will be Angular and the backend will be Spring-boot. I am trying to find a sample project or hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I do not want to make a monolithic application, more micro service type application.

Answer (score 1):

One approcach would be to generate an EAR and deploy it to any enterprise application server.
If you are using maven, then you can have achieve this using a multi-module project.
For this approach you can have 3 child modules and 1 parent module.
You can put the front end code in one module and let the pom.xml generate a WAR out of it.
The second module will have all your back-end code and its pom will generate a JAR (or a WAR is also fine).
The third module will do nothing apart from simply packing the JAR and the WAR into an EAR.
These three modules will be the child modules.
The parent module is just the aggregator module which will execute the pom for each of its child modules. This way, you will you will end up having a JAR, WAR and an EAR. 
The EAR is the one that you will deploy to your server.

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to do, I am just trying to find an good example. I only ever done it under one module. I know in the third pom file I'll define the `modules` like `<module>frontend</module>` but putting it all together with Angular 2 and boot is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Checkout this [article](http://daveshepherd.co.uk/2012-06-multi-module-project-maven). This is just a skeleton though.

Answer (score 0):

This [sample application](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/spring-boot-4tw-uni) and [the presentation that goes with it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cemYpV1fNI) describe a way to organize your Spring Boot application with a frontend/backend module while still leveraging the devtools features.

Comment: At first glance it seems like what I am looking for but its not clicking so to speak. I am looking more into the project now. Forgive my ignorance but I have only ever made my applications under one module and put the frontend under `resources/webapps`.